# Button click event not found?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Q:
Am I crazy? I've got the event. The name's copy/pasted so I know it's no typo. What am I missing here? 
*(Don't worry about parameters, please, this is for training and I've been told not to use them at this time)*

```
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UdpEPL" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" Visible="False">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnEpl" EventName="BtnEpl_Click" />
            </Triggers>
      <ContentTemplate> 

      <!--some label and textbox controls-->

      <br />
      <asp:Button ID="BtnEpl" runat="server" Text="Submit" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    onclick="BtnEpl_Click" />
      <br />

      <!--the second update panel-->

         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UdpEplShow" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" Visible="False">
                  <Triggers>
                           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnEpl" EventName="BtnEpl_Click" />
                  </Triggers>
         <ContentTemplate>      
      <!--more labels displaying the user input from the first update panel-->
```

**The codebehind:**

```
 protected void BtnEpl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string EplQuery = "INSERT INTO EPL (Entity, Employees, CA, MI, NY, NJ, Primex, EplLim, EplSir, Premium, Wage, Sublim) VALUES ('" + TbEplEntity + "', '" + TbEplTotalEmpl + "', '" + TbEplCalEmpl + "', '" + TbEplMichEmpl + "', '" + TbEplNyEmpl + "', '" + TbEplNjEmpl + "', '" + TbEplPrimEx + "', '" + TbEplLim + "', '" + TbEplEplSir + "', '" + TbEplPrem + "', '" + TbEplWage + "', '" + TbEplInvestCost + "')";
            string EplIdQuery = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS LastInsertedInstanceId";

        using (SqlConnection EplConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            EplConn.Open();
            SqlCommand EplCmd = new SqlCommand(EplQuery, EplConn);
            SqlCommand EplIdCmd = new SqlCommand(EplIdQuery, EplConn);
            using (EplCmd)
            using (EplIdCmd)
            {
                EplCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader EplDr = EplIdCmd.ExecuteReader();
                EplDr.Read();
                int lastInsertedInstanceId = Convert.ToInt32(EplDr[0]);


            }

            string x = Request.QueryString["InstanceId"];
            string EplShowQuery = "SELECT Entity, Employees, CA, MI, NY, NJ, Primex, EplLim, EplSir, Premium, Wage, Sublim FROM EPL WHERE InstanceId =" + x;
            using (SqlCommand EplShowCmd = new SqlCommand(EplShowQuery, EplConn))
            {
                SqlDataReader EplDr = EplShowCmd.ExecuteReader();
                EplDr.Read();
                LblEplShowEntity.Text = EplDr.GetString(0);
                LblEplShowTotalEmpl.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                LblEplShowCalEmpl.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                LblEplShowMichEmpl.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                LblEplShowNyEmpl.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                LblEplShowNjEmpl.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                LblEplShowPrimEx.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                LblEplShowLim.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                LblEplShowSir.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                LblEplShowPrem.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(9).ToString();
                LblEplShowWage.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(10).ToString();
                LblEplShowInvestCost.Text = EplDr.GetInt32(11).ToString();

            }
        }
            UdpEPL.Visible = false;
            UdpEplShow.Visible = true;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in the interest of giving this question an answer, I must point out my mistake. @Muhammad asked me why the panels were set to visible=false; this was because of the way I tried to approach the page structure. I wanted to use ajax to display input forms, and then hide them upon submission to the db and display the data in read-only format, so I thought I'd put both forms in update panels and make them invisible until they were called by the dropdownlist. Unfortunately what I discovered is that triggers won't fire on invisible controls. Don't quote me, but as I understand it, this is because invisible server side controls don't send markup to the browser. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 4):

In trigger, you only need to specify event Name.

It should be

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnEpl" EventName="Click" />
```

instead

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnEpl" EventName="BtnEpl_Click" />
```

Comment: So I don't use the actual event handler name from the codebehind (BtnEpl_Click)? I should just use 'Click'?

Comment: Yah, we only need to use Event name not the handler name. just try :)

Comment: @Brazos: The property is called **EventName** .

Comment: Well, the page will load, but I've got a dead button now. I get no action when I click. Why is that?

Comment: Why you set this Visible="False" ? update panel should be visible to work.

Comment: @Muhammad: I have the panels invisible because the first panel is made visible only when the product "EPL" is selected from a drop down list. Then, when the user inputs the information into those textboxes, the submit button makes the first update panel invisible, and makes the second panel visible. This second panel is a read-only display of the same data.

Comment: you should make visible=ture and I have seen nothing is there in that panel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the First ContentTemplate at some point? In case you do it after the Button Markup please enable ChildrenAsTriggers="true".